# Swift: How to Expand a cell in a TableView (containing EKEvent-stuff)?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Okay! So first of all I know there´s a lot of simplification to be done with te code provided below. But i runs just fine at least :)

Also, If you want me to make it easier with providing more code, just let me know.

I've seen some tutorials on how to expand/collapse a cell and populating the sections with data etc. But they only show it with using simple arrays.

My problem is that I've buil sort of a Calendar-app and I want to expand a cell containing some EKEvent stuff.

I want to be able to tap my cell that contains the EKEvent-title and that would ecpand the cell to below show startDate, notes etc.

Anyone that are willing to explain this in a pedagogical way? :)

Here's the code to my ViewController (with what I believe is the relevant code)

'''
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print ("You selected a row!")

    if calendar.selectedDate == nil  {
        print (dateFormatter.string(from: calendar.today!))
        switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event) {
        case .notDetermined:
            let eventStore = EKEventStore()
            eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, error) in
                if granted {
                    // do stuff
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.showEventViewController()
                    }
                }
            }
        case .authorized:
            // do stuff
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.showEventViewController()
            }
        default:
            break
        }
        
      
        let calendar1 = Calendar.current
        var dateComponents = DateComponents.init()
        dateComponents.day = 1 // days from today
        
        let futureDate = calendar1.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: calendar.today!)
        
        let eventsPredicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: calendar.today!, end: futureDate!, calendars: nil)
        
    
        let fetchedEvents = eventStore.events(matching: eventsPredicate)
        
        print (fetchedEvents[indexPath.row].eventIdentifier!)
        let eventID = String(fetchedEvents[indexPath.row].eventIdentifier)
        
        print (eventID)
        
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm"
        
        let eventVC = EKEventEditViewController()
    
        eventVC.editViewDelegate = self // don't forget the delegate
 
        eventVC.event = eventStore.event(withIdentifier: eventID)
    
        present(eventVC, animated: true)
    }
    
    else {
        print ((dateFormatter.string(from: calendar.selectedDate!)))
        
        switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event) {
        case .notDetermined:
            let eventStore = EKEventStore()
            eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, error) in
                if granted {
                    // do stuff
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.showEventViewController()
                    }
                }
            }
        case .authorized:
            // do stuff
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.showEventViewController()
            }
        default:
            break
        }
        
      
        let calendar1 = Calendar.current
        var dateComponents = DateComponents.init()
        dateComponents.day = 1 // days from today
        
        let futureDate = calendar1.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: calendar.selectedDate!)
        
        let eventsPredicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: calendar.selectedDate!, end: futureDate!, calendars: nil)
        
    
        let fetchedEvents = eventStore.events(matching: eventsPredicate)
        
        print (fetchedEvents[indexPath.row].eventIdentifier!)
        let eventID = String(fetchedEvents[indexPath.row].eventIdentifier)
        
        print (eventID)
        
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm"
        
        let eventVC = EKEventEditViewController()
    
        eventVC.editViewDelegate = self // don't forget the delegate
 
        eventVC.event = eventStore.event(withIdentifier: eventID)
    
        present(eventVC, animated: true)
     
    }
}
```

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    if calendar.selectedDate == nil {
        
        return eventStore.events(matching: eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: calendar.today!, end: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents.init(day: 1), to: calendar.today!)!, calendars: nil)).count  }
    
    else {
        
        return eventStore.events(matching: eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: calendar.selectedDate!, end: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents.init(day: 1), to: calendar.selectedDate!)!, calendars: nil)).count
    }
    
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   
   return 1
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    

 let dayTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dayTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    let calendar1 = Calendar.current
    var dateComponents = DateComponents.init()
    dateComponents.day = 1 // days from today
    
    if calendar.selectedDate == nil  {
        
        let futureDate = calendar1.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: calendar.today!)
        
        let eventsPredicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: calendar.today!, end: futureDate!, calendars: nil)
        
        let fetchedEvents = eventStore.events(matching: eventsPredicate)
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
   
        let eventStartTimeFormatter = fetchedEvents[indexPath.row].startDate
        let eventStartTime = dayTimeFormatter.string(for: eventStartTimeFormatter)
            
        let eventEndTimeFormatter = fetchedEvents[indexPath.row].endDate
        let eventEndTime = dayTimeFormatter.string(for: eventEndTimeFormatter)
    
        cell.textLabel?.text = ("\(eventStartTime!.description) \("-") \(eventEndTime!.description) \(fetchedEvents[indexPath.row].title.description)")
        
        return cell
        
    }
    
    
    else {
        
        let futureDate = calendar1.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: calendar.selectedDate!)
        
        let eventsPredicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: calendar.selectedDate!, end: futureDate!, calendars: nil)
  
        let fetchedEvents = eventStore.events(matching: eventsPredicate)
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        
        let eventStartTimeFormatter = fetchedEvents[indexPath.row].startDate
        let eventStartTime = dayTimeFormatter.string(for: eventStartTimeFormatter)
        
        let eventEndTimeFormatter = fetchedEvents[indexPath.row].endDate
        let eventEndTime = dayTimeFormatter.string(for: eventEndTimeFormatter)
    
        cell.textLabel?.text = ("\(eventStartTime!.description) \("-") \(eventEndTime!.description) \(fetchedEvents[indexPath.row].title.description)")
                   
        print (fetchedEvents[indexPath.row].eventIdentifier as Any)

        return cell
        
        }
    
}
```

'''

Comment: *"I'm quite new to Swift"* ... start simple. Create a cell that has two labels, and learn how to expand/collapse the cell to show/hide the second label. Then add a couple more labels (or other UI elements), and expand/collapse to show/hide the additional elements. ***THEN*** start working on implementing that with your EKEvent data.

Comment: truth hurts :)  I guess there´s no shortcuts